# How to implement the HTTP POST Request using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have to do this request through using resttemplate. 
key is valid, and other (GET) request ive successfully implemmented. But with this i have a problem

```
response = Unirest.post("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/v1.0")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "somekey")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .field("country", "US")
        .field("currency", "USD")
        .field("locale", "en-US")
        .field("originPlace", "MSQ-sky")
        .field("destinationPlace", "DME-sky")
        .field("outboundDate", "2019-05-01")
        .field("adults", 1)
        .asJson();
response.getHeaders();
```

I've trying, but i always get 401

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-RapidAPI-Host", "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
headers.set("X-RapidAPI-Key", RAPID_API_KEY);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("country", "US");
map.add("currency", "USD");
map.add("locale", "en-US");
map.add("originPlace", "MSQ-sky");
map.add("destinationPlace", "DME-sky");
map.add("outboundDate", "2019-05-01");
map.add("adults", "1");
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, ObjectNode.class);
```

Where is mistake?
**UPDATED**   This request doesnt works in SPRING 5, in spring 4 its works.

Comment: Can you format your code before asking for help ?

Comment: sorry, its first question this, I thought it would be formatted

Comment: Is your key (`RAPID_API_KEY`) valid?

Comment: sure, the key is valid and works with other requests

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `HttpEntity` request, you should pass headers as a second argument [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html):

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
```

Comment: ive changed, and now im getting 403

Comment: The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

Comment: i understand what does mean 403. look at first example(Unirest)  its works. how i can do that by resttemplate